# angularjs filter null values in json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

My Json array is as follows

```
[["2017-01-11",8327.8,8389.0,8322.25,8380.65,192285417.0,8938.68],["2017-01-10",8262.7,8293.8,8261.0,8288.6,147312927.0,6904.57],["2017-01-09",8259.35,8263.0,8227.75,8236.05,102211190.0,5197.62],["2017-01-06",8281.85,8306.85,8233.25,8243.8,143689850.0,7298.74],["2017-01-05",8226.65,8282.65,8223.7,8273.8,163957452.0,8180.68],["2017-01-04",8202.65,8218.5,8180.9,8190.5,136476345.0,6543.13],["2017-01-03",8196.05,8219.1,8148.6,8192.25,131186021.0,6053.67],["2017-01-02",8210.1,8212.0,8133.8,8179.5,null,null],["2016-12-30",8119.65,8197.0,8114.75,8185.8,131457250.0,5800.7],["2016-12-29",8030.6,8111.1,8020.8,8103.6,null,null]]
```

I am using following angular js script to pull up records

```
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Sno.</th>
              <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{ header }}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="(key,info) in row">{{info}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
```

Angular JS Code

```
                $http.jsonp(url)
                    .success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.headers=data.dataset.column_names;
                    $scope.description=data.dataset.description;
                    $scope.data=data.dataset.data;
                });
```

The issue is that code breaks where it finds null value in row in array.For example entire row `["2017-01-02",8210.1,8212.0,8133.8,8179.5,null,null]`
is missed from table since it has null values in end.

The output I am getting is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isMCa.png)

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: Why don't you check null for data in .success event handler before accessing its fields?

Answer (score 0):

Check in backend function if the values you want to insert in the json object is not null and insert it if the condition is true.